# DivisionByZeroError not cached in php5.6

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-5.6

I'm trying to catch a DivisionByZeroError but is not working , Istill get the division by zero error message

```
try{
            //incidencia
            $html = "<div id='incidence'>
            <div><h4>$table</h4></div>
            <div>"
            .$this->drawTable($this->setIncidence($tables)).
                    "<p><b>Duración Válidas MEDIA: </b>".$this->getAverageDuration($tables)." minutos</p>"
                    ."<p><b>Duración Válidas MEDIANA: </b>".$this->calculate_median($tables)." minutos</p>"
                ."<div>";

            //validas        
            $html .= "<div id='filters'>
            <div><h4>Válidas</h4></div>
                <div>"
                    .$this->drawTable($this->setValidsTable($tables)).
                "</div>
            </div>
            </div>";
            //filtros
            //var_dump($this->setFilterTable($tables));
            $html .= "<div id='filters'>
                    <div><h4>Filtros</h4></div>
                    <div>"
                        .$this->drawTable($this->setFilterTable($tables)).
                    "</div>
                </div></div>";
            //incoherencias        
            $html .= "<div id='inco'>
                <div><h4>Incoherencias</h4></div>
                <div>"
                    .$this->drawTable($this->setIncoTable($tables)).
                "</div>
            </div>";
            echo  $html;
        }catch(DivisionByZeroError $error){
            echo "No existen datos";
        }
```

There some of the called functions inside  the try can make a division by zero.

Comment: "*Division by zero*" is a warning, and therefor not caught in `catch`. Fix the functions instead. Example: `if ($divisor == 0) { return 0; } echo $divider / $divisor;`

Comment: Try error_reporting(-1); to see the error.

Comment: Where in all that code is that error thrown? Additionally, are you sure that code will work on PHP 5.6? That `DivisionByZeroError` got added in PHP 7.0 and is not available on 5.6